# Trying to use Windows Runtime Extensions in Windows Phone Static Library project (C++)

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, static-libraries

I've created windows phone C++ static library project. 
Set created flag "Consume Windows Runtime Extension" to Yes (/ZW).

But when I try to use anything from Platform:: namespace, compiler brings me errors like this:

> Error 78 error C3083: 'Platform': the symbol to the left of a '::'
>   must be a type C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\include\vccorlib.h 103 1 MyProjectName

Creating dll keeps same errors.

Is anybody knows if it is really possible to use Windows Runtime Extension in libraries for windows phone? And have any suggestions to solve this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is definitely possible to use Windows Runtime Extensions for a Windows Phone static library.

It looks like you're not picking up the correct include directories in your project.

You need to make sure that your static library project is created specifically as a *Windows Phone* static library (i.e. compiled against the "v110_wp" platform toolset).